# Copy from one Excel Application To Sheet Without Changing Dates VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy an entire sheet from one application sheet to another open one with the following code

```
'Open Application
MsgBox "Select Report"
Dim my_FileName3 As Variant
my_FileName3 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & _
    "*.xl*", 1, "Select ManMan File", "Open", False)
If my_FileName <> False Then
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName3
End If

'Set Active
var3 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Copy Everything
 Dim lastRow3 As Long
 lastRow3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Range("a1:z" & lastRow3).Copy Destination:=Workbooks   (var1).Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Var1R)

'Close Worksheet
 Workbooks(var3).Close False
```

This code above works but the problem is the dates have been completely changed.

[image: First Document Worksheet Before copy]

[image: Second Application Sheet4 After copy]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Ignore the empty row.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `If my_FileName <> False Then` should be `If my_FileName3 <> False Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the dates can be explained by inconsistent use of the date system between the two workbooks.  One will be using the 1904 date system, and one won't be:

[image]

If the destination workbook is using the 1904 date system, you will need to subtract 1462 from each value copied in order to convert it back to the same date that you started with.